# How to update vsam file records?

Tags: cics, vsam

I want to read a VSAM file record using CICS commands and then update it using REWITE command,  but I have two major problems:

1. throu readnext operation to access a vsam record, for some of the records, i need to access database and do some process there, finally commit database changes. But the thing is whenever I commit the database, the readnext encounters an error INVREC, which dosnt allow to access next records in VSAM file.
2. When accessing any record in VSAM file, I need to update the record in file, so I used REWRITE CMMAND, which returns error number 16.

Overall I want to do the following process:
1.Read a VSAM file records one by one using READNEXT comand
2. Access database and do commit
3. Rewrite the VSAM file record using REWRITE command.

Comment: Usually you'd want the commit of the database to happen transactionally with the write to the file; either both are updated, or neither. Are you sure you don't want that to happen?

Comment: I want both of them occur together.

Answer (score 2):

1. The Db2 COMMIT also causes a SYNCPOINT for CICS resources.  As documented on the STARTBR command, "A browse can end by using the ENDBR, SYNCPOINT, or SYNCPOINT ROLLBACK commands. Also an implicit sync point at the end of task ends the browse."  So once you issue the COMMIT for Db2, you must restart the browse by issuing a new STARTBR command.
2. You cannot issue a REWRITE command unless the READ (or READNEXT) specified the UPDATE option. READNEXT with UPDATE is only supported by VSAM files that were opened in RLS (Record Level Sharing) mode.

In your scenario you probably need to do the following:

- Issue STARTBR to start the browse of the VSAM file.
- Issue READNEXT to get the first VSAM record.
- Save the key of the record that was retrieved.
- Access the database
- Issue Db2 COMMIT or CICS SYNCPOINT
- Issue READ UPDATE for the record key that was saved
- Issue REWRITE for the file
- Issue STARTBR with the saved key.
- Issue READNEXT
- If record returned is the one just updated, issue READNEXT to get the next record.
- Loop back to the SQL statement to access the database.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped me a lot. I have one other question. I searched a lot but I didnt find ueful document. How can I access a VSAM file in RLS mode? I also found some example of READNEXT with update option that just is applied to vsam file in RLS mode.

Answer (score 1):

The file itself needs to be defined with a log parameter and logstreamid if you want it to be forward recoverable. The CICS definition can then be changed to be RLS(YES).

Just to cover the bases, the CICS region also needs SIT Parameter RLS set to YES.

Comment: The problem is that I dont know how to add ´RLS(YES)´ to CICS definition. Could you please give me an example on how to do it.

Comment: Certainly, assuming your CICS definitions are held in the CICS System Definition (CSD) dataset you need to change the definition and then install it in the CICS system.

Assuming your file is called "myfile", it can be located by the command

"CEDA EXPAND GROUP(*) FILE(myfile)"

This will show all file definitions in the CSD called "myfile" - type an "a" alongside the definition to alter it.

On the screen that appears, there is a field "RLSACCESS" which needs to be set to "yes". Pressing enter will store that entry in the CSD and F3 will end the CEDA transaction.